# eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework-master or eg-01-csharp-jwt-core-master examples, RequestJWTUserToken dont work for me

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working with the official Docusign eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework-master example to impersonate my user in my sandbox (demo) environment and fire some Rest API calls.

I did everything like the fallows sources:
   1-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymYzB0mJAVk
   2-https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-core

Here my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="b4c84ba8-(...)-ecc43e44da91" />
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="4cebdc19-(...)-d53217530f3af" />
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="signer@gmail.com" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="Signer" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="CC@gmail.com" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="CC" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAoLjoMkaQXdN71O4+D+GqGHh6GnAzfJv6HGlnC/gOVMlxYQCk&#xA;
BQxqdzcoLpPh+r4qTlbeO0Sv2qL5+uRgZT8zIwCMDdwEtRcVKSbiDBI14hFZJDmi&#xA;
xfXPH9eAKI7hfwOn4isj1g4Hc9v24O9J2PVpzcQSWxD1Z2D5EQU6fHEfBYaaEg0N&#xA;
tBojRaKnnVaIw2uNJsHdwJafVyoGoFwmRSMnDmcQWwgnra51rLScoKI9ccAW0g9z&#xA;
bdvosce0SqPPQN3QW8AbLf8Gg4CnTIWmLdKxTVTwLcTeXJl7cJtR5xcIBLa+XXm5&#xA;
(...)
94X09g/6FHtwKE2PxfMFimGJET1BjFlfzEa2LrMaQH8VXqMn1/rGdRglsufA+c7A&#xA;
Dei+oYB/jNg/vTUUQm52KjLOBDpPp21XEGELvscCgYAZRwPrRRuA4Gnk8UWO3REz&#xA;
afQcqD23+9wn6iwzVTCP1585+3nhWEr5cW0Rjt1SmizOraknouyEBF3lwKH05fs/&#xA;
1vBYBlA+RiRliZnBeK+s1H/C5A7UAQ38PileQEV06cA3qZiPRZshISrlBpj/BdhN&#xA;
Jc240QGDvs63qg76YyelUQKBgBljKoC0L3oIlfUFPj2wiJM3+VcQvzdztt+C8x7P&#xA;
obJMO2w3zN0qFasr4s/kPdIsJVCKAPeppt8KDShLuWabmWh5F5lalIJp9BlDxQgK&#xA;
W4DO/wrpy0VRFXW4HqhnhLP6wzWF8H7YSHE0avM9eW0Bw1nH8A5R6eGiaZ3yFua1&#xA;
WtNnAoGBALFR6NW4WDM+tZeK773kIFG0zGUIRhJ6u3W4K5dhbmOgrSYxyhEBWRVk&#xA;
gbBrKvLp//61SpaYmRGe5Qy1BZaSuee+VYZJOTVHSl0EZvXjT4BKg3sJq0IwV7/3&#xA;
c9d3MxKxhcpE7Et3ULKmWnlapJX8vxj5y7cNFz0cEV+rfIne8mqB&#xA;
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I tried everything but the console always fire the same error in the *RequestJWTUserToken* method  present in the ExampleBase.cs:

Sending an envelope with three documents. This takes about 15 seconds...
Obtaining a new access token...

```
 DocuSign Exception!
    Reason: 400
    Error Reponse: {"error":"invalid_request"}
 Done. Hit enter to exit...
```

I tested all the ways to pass the private keys, here my code:

```
private void UpdateToken()
{ 

            //String privatekey from the .pem file
            String privateKeyString = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/jterrero/Desktop/DocSign Lab/WorkSpace/.Net_Core_Keys/PrivateKey.pem");

            //String privatekey from the DSConfig.PrivateKey Property in DSConfig.cs
            //String privateKeyString = DSConfig.PrivateKey;

            byte[] privateKeyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKeyString);

            OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                            DSConfig.ClientID,
                            DSConfig.ImpersonatedUserGuid,
                            DSConfig.AuthServer,
                            privateKeyByte,
                            1);

            //(...)
        }
```

Note! My access data all is fine. I know that because when I run the eg-01-node-jwt-master present in the fallow source: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt with the same privileges(DS_CLIENT_ID,DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID,DS_AUTH_SERVER,DS_PRIVATE_KEY, and OAuthRedirectURI) run perfectly!

Note: I have the same OAuthRedirectURI in both places: my dsConfig.cs file and the Additional settings/Redirect URIs in my Api & Keys Integration Key.

Please if can help me!! I'm on the black hole here. I don't know what more to do!
Thanks in advance!
JT

Comment: Try setting `DS_AUTH_SERVER` in `App.config` as `account-d.docusign.com` instead of `https://account-d.docusign.com`

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Nothing! looks like the actual configuration that offers Docusign in their youtube and GitHub examples don't work. But I resolved my issue getting the correct App.config from the default solution that implements the extension for Visual Studio. That configuration works perfectly! Here the link : https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-introducing-the-docusign-visual-studio-extension/                       just in the case helps somebody! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a configuration issue. Seems like one way to solve is to use the Visual Studio extension that would automatically set everything up for you for either JWT or Auth Code Grant.
Here is where you can download the VS extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension